# how to set meta description with dangerouslysetinnerhtml in helmet

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

i want to set meta content with using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, can anyone please help me, how we can do that ? here i have added code for it, any help will be really appreciated.
here i have placed my code, but getting error 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' is not defined

```
  <Helmet>
                    <meta property="og:description"   content={ dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ __html: event?.description } } />
                </Helmet>
```

Comment: hey, can you show me how your source goes, after you use react-helmet? I tried using it but couldnt work it out

Answer (score 0):

it should be used as an object property, not as an attribute value. Also, it hould be passed as a prop to the content property

```
<Helmet>
  <meta property="og:description" content={
    { __html: event?.description }
  } />
</Helmet>
```

Comment: getting this in html <meta property="og:description" content="[object Object]" data-react-helmet="true">

Comment: that is because description is an object, not a string. it has to be string or number or something like that in order it to work, objects and arrays are 'forbidden'